# Wordpress webpage is very slow to load

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here in my webpage it is very slow to load.very first I thought it was the problem of plugins and images in my site
but here am using less mb images and nice plugins
any suggestions?

Comment: Where is link of website?

Comment: I suggest you make it go faster.

Comment: Please share the link of your website.

Comment: here my site url is shireen.se

Answer (score 0):

Check you web page in
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

or
https://gtmetrix.com/

And follow the necessary steps to make your site faster.